# Include a red dot in a Tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to do a figure in TikZ, and the compilation works but it doesn't include the red vertex.

Here is the copy of my code and then the error message:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,positioning, decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,petri,calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\SmallMatrix[1]{{%

  \tiny\arraycolsep=0.3\arraycolsep\ensuremath{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}}}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \tkzDefPoint(0,-0.17){a}
    \tkzDrawPoints[color=red,fill=red,size=12](a)
    \node at ($(0.5,-1.1)$)    {$C_1$}; 
    \node at ($(-0.5,-1.1)$)    {$C_2$}; 
    \draw (-0.1,0) to  (0.5,-1);
    \draw (0.1,0) to  (-0.5,-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}



\caption{Step $1$}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is the error message :

> l.38 \tkzDefPoint (0,-0.17){a} The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined. Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont! Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont! Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont! Missing character: There is no - in font nullfont! Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont! Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont! Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont! Missing character: There is no 7 in font nullfont! Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont! Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont! ! Undefined control sequence. l.40 \tkzDrawPoints [color=red,fill=red,size=12](a) The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,`\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,`I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Also it's working on the computer of my friend. So I am pretty confused (I used the same packages as him). I'm taking on Sharelatex. Many thanks in advance !

Comment: add `\usepackage{tkz-euclide} ` to your preamble...

Comment: Or change the two `\tkz` commands to a regular TikZ one.

Comment: By the way: you loaded `tikz` and `xy` twice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would rather draw this image in pure `tikz`:

[image]

the *mwe* after considering above comments regarding your document preamble and fact that `mathtools` call `amsmath˙`, `amssymb` call `amssfonts`, `tikz` call `pgf` and that `hyperref` had to be with exception of `cleveref` the last in preamble, is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
\newcommand\SmallMatrix[1]{{%
\tiny\arraycolsep=0.3\arraycolsep\ensuremath{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}}}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,positioning, decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,petri,calc}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\linespread{1.3}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\fill[red] (0,-0.17) circle (1pt);
\draw ( 0.1,0) -- (-0.5,-1) node[below] {$C_1$};
\draw (-0.1,0) -- ( 0.5,-1) node[below] {$C_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Step $1$}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Zarko's answer. But why not let `tikz` do the job of finding the intersection?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\coordinate (A) at (0.1,0);
\coordinate (B) at (-0.5,-1);
\draw [name path=A--B] (A) -- (B) node[below] {$C_1$};
\coordinate (C) at (-0.1,0);
\coordinate (D) at ( 0.5,-1);
\draw [name path=C--D] (C) -- (D) node[below] {$C_2$};
\path [name intersections={of=A--B and C--D,by=E}];
\node [circle, fill=red,label=-90:$E$] at (E) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Step $1$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```